# GraphQL enum union workaround?

Tags: enums, graphql

I have Major categories and Minor Categories that belong to a Major category.
Both are ENUM type.
I want client to choose matching minor category ENUM to submit with its Major category.
I don't want to include all different minor category ENUMs as fields.

I first tried doing
`union MinorCategories = Minor1 | Minor2`
However this failed because `union` only works with `ObjectTypes`

Enforcing minor category depending on the major category is not necessary. I only want to receive one field that can be selective by the client by ENUM.
Is there any work around?

Answer (score 10):

[GraphQL does not support union types for scalar values, only for object types](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/215).
One option, albeit an ugly one, is to wrap your enums in an object type.

```
type Minor1Wrapper {
  value: Minor1!
}

type Minor2Wrapper {
  value: Minor2!
}

union MinorCategories = Minor1Wrapper | Minor2Wrapper
```